# how to get date using moment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am getting string in this formate "p+2", "p+1" or "p-1","p-2".P reperest the current date or today's date.I want to add days after seen the string .If "p+2" then I need to add two days .if string is "p-1" I need to subtract one day ? can we use moment library .

I try like this but struck to get perfect result ? it pass on case one ..but fail on case 2 ..why ?
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaKKVw

```
var case1="p+1";
//or
var case2="p-1";

//or
var case3="p";

    function getValue(str){
      var formatedDate;
      if(str.indexOf('+')!==-1){
        var i=str.indexOf('+');
       formatedDate= moment().add(str.substring(i,str.length), 'days')
      }else if(str.indexOf('-')!==-1){
           var i=str.indexOf('-');
        formatedDate= moment().subtract(str.substring(i,str.length), 'days')
      }
      return formatedDate;
    }

    alert(getValue(case2));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the add method like

```js
function getDate(string) {
  return moment().startOf('day').add(+string.substring(1) || 0, 'day').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
}

snippet.log(getDate('p'))
snippet.log(getDate('p+1'))
snippet.log(getDate('p-1'))
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `str.substring(i+1,str.length)` instead of `str.substring(i,str.length)`